# Float a img near a p with css

Tags: html, css, css-float

Simply the image is shown wrong. Where is the mistake? 
http://felipelopez.com.ar/prueba/

Comment: Please feel free to ask your question again, providing context, code, and details. Don't link to an outside resource as this may result in a worthless question in the future.

Comment: Impossible to tell when you're using an external stylesheet. But it looks like a space issue, extend the body div that contains all the words and the picture. Also, maybe set it to overflow:hidden although that isn't entirely necessary.

Comment: @DominicB-c - Try adding a clear, that is the problem, without clearing floats they affect layout height as if they weren't there.

Comment: @David Yes I think you're right, but I would also add that there are a few solutions to this problem, without the css we can't be 100% sure of the problem. It may be that the body is a little bit too short although I suspect it's probably set to auto and your answer is probably the most likely to be right.

Comment: @DominicB-c - Indeed you are right there could be a variety of solutions, but I went and checked the sites CSS myself and tested with inspect element ;-)

Comment: @David that effort deserves an upvote, I just took a quick look at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear a float once it has been used, e.g. after the paragraph do:

```
<br style="clear: both;" />
```

Some doc's on it: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

You'd obviously want to do this as a class, so your code uses better practices. There are other ways of clearing, but the 
 clear is the easiest, with the least amount of CSS.